# Conservation of energy in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian

In Griffiths' book *Introduction to quantum mechanics* (second edition, page 37) it states:

> The time-independent Schrödinger equation says $$\hat{H} \psi_{n} = E_{n}\psi_{n}$$ so
>   $$\langle H \rangle = \int \Psi^* H \Psi dx = \int \left(\sum c_{m} \psi_{m}\right)^*H\left(\sum c_{n} \psi_{n}\right)dx = \sum |c_{n}|^{2}E_{n}$$

This shows that the probability of getting a particular energy is independent of time.

I don't see how we obtain $\int \Psi^* H \Psi dx = \int (\sum c_{m} \psi_{m})^*H(\sum c_{n} \psi_{n})dx $ since $\Psi(x,t) = \sum c_{n} \psi_{n}e^{-iE_{n}t}$ (it is not clear that the exponentials cancel as this would explain it).

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Hint: You have a series of orthogonal basis functions. The only overlap is between the same basis function on each side of H.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The full work-through goes as follows:
\begin{align}
⟨H⟩
& =
\int \Psi^* H \Psi dx
\\ & =
\int \left(\sum_m e^{-iE_m t}c_{m} \psi_{m}\right)^*H\left(\sum_n e^{-iE_n t}c_{n} \psi_{n}\right)\mathrm dx
\\ & =
\sum_m \sum_n e^{iE_m t}e^{-iE_n t}c_{m}^* c_{n}\int  \psi_{m}^*H \psi_{n}\mathrm dx
\\ & =
\sum_m \sum_n e^{i(E_m-E_n) t}c_{m}^* c_{n}\int  \psi_{m}^* E_n\psi_{n}\mathrm dx \tag{$\ast$}
\\ & =
\sum_m \sum_n e^{i(E_m-E_n) t}c_{m}^* c_{n}E_n\int  \psi_{m}^* \psi_{n}\mathrm dx \tag{$\ast$}
\\ & =
\sum_m \sum_n e^{i(E_m -E_n) t}c_{m}^* c_{n}E_n\delta_{mn}  \tag{$\star$}
\\ & = \sum_n |c_{n}|^{2}E_{n}
\end{align}
and, crucially, it relies on the orthogonality of the $\psi_n$ to go from $(\ast)$ to $(\star)$. That imposes $m=n$ inside the sum, which kills the exponentials.